# Create a file at a given path using C++ in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, file, path

I want to create a file at a given path that is relative to the current directory. The following code behaves erratically. I some times see the file created and some times do not. That may be because of the change in the current directory. Here's the code.

```
//for appending timestamp
timeval ts;
gettimeofday(&ts,NULL);
std::string timestamp = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(ts.tv_sec);
//./folder/inner_folder is an existing directory
std::string filename = "./folder/inner_folder/abc_"+timestamp+ ".csv";
std::ofstream output_file(filename);
output_file << "abc,efg";
output_file.close();
```

Now, the problem is the file is created only in some cases. That is when I have as a command line argument an input file from the current directory, it works fine.

```
./program input_file
```

If I have something like this, it does not work

```
./program ./folder1/input_file
```

I tried giving the full path as an argument for `ofstream`, I still don't see the files created.

What is the correct way to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

`ofstream` will not create missing directories in the file path, you must ensure the directories exist and if not create them using OS specific api or [boost's file system library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm).

Always check the result of IO operations, and query system error code to determine reason for failures:

```
if (output_ file.is_open())
{
    if (!(output_file << "abc,efg"))
    {
        // report error.
    }
}
else
{
    const int last_error = errno;
    std::cerr << "failed to open "
              << filename
              << ": "
              << strerror(last_error)
              << std::endl;
}
```